# getting context from bluetooth in android source

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-source

I am modifying android open source code, and I'd like to be able to get Context information within the BluetoothAdapter class. So far there doesn't seem to be a direct way to do it. For example, there is an mService field, but it is an interface and not a real Service object, so I can't call getApplicationContext() from it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Context is associated with Service, Application or Activity. In your case there is nothing like this. I'll advise you to have a look at the `frameworks/base/core/java/android/server/BluetoothService.java` maybe there you can implement your functionality.

Comment: Do you know how BluetoothService is used on the server side? I want to be able to detect when an application is using a device's bluetooth to discover other devices and/or exchange information, and I want to know which application is doing this. Do you have any suggestions on how to modify BluetoothService to achieve this goal?

Comment: Actually, I do not know. This topic is out of my interest. If I find something I'll write you.